# How can I disable map repeater in the World Google Map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using world map via Google Map API and World map is going to repeat. I want to disable the same. I am using this code

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:700px"></div>

<script>
var lat = 0;
var lang = 0;

var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: centerLatLng,
  scrollwheel: false,
  zoom: 3,
  minZoom: 1
});
</script>
```

Comment: It would be helpfull if you make a working example of your problem for us

Comment: Please check this link. https://jsfiddle.net/dinesh10641/tyzhydu0/2/

Comment: In which World map is going to repeat again and again. Can you help me out.

Comment: Only thing i can think off is to match the "size" of the world map. this might give you an idea how to "solve" it. https://jsfiddle.net/obgvk1eo/

Comment: But when we drag the map left or right then it is repeating again.

Comment: Then i guess you will have to make a script that dont allow you to drag it at some specific zoom level or x/y cords

Comment: You telling about reduce the width of the map.

Comment: hmm, Thank You, Andersen. Let me do the same and will update.

Comment: related question: [How to enable horizontally world repeat in google maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947413/how-to-enable-horizontally-world-repeat-in-google-maps)

Comment: duplicate of [Display world map with no repeats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498210/display-world-map-with-no-repeats)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any repeats, you need to control the minimum zoom allowed and the width of your map to be less than or equal to one width of of the base tiles at the minimum zoom level allowed on your map. [Check out this answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20500708/7510798)